# Is there a way to loop through the array that would hide the columns depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for the loop that would hide all the irrelevant columns depending on cell value.
So in "sheet 1" I have a name range "identifier" and depending on value of the identifier only specific columns in sheet2 would stay open all the rest (apart form column A ) would be hidden . For Example:

- if sheet1 Range("identifier") = "111111111" then sheet2 columns ("B:E") stay unhidden
- if sheet1 Range("identifier") = "222222222" then sheet2 columns ("F:I") stay unhidden
- if sheet1 Range("identifier") = "333333333" then sheet2 columns ("J:M") stay unhidden
- if sheet1 Range("identifier") = "444444444" then sheet2 columns ("N:Q") stay unhidden
- if sheet1 Range("identifier") = "555555555" then sheet2 columns ("R:U") stay unhidden

Column A:A in Sheet 2 would always stay open

Is there a way to do this in a nice neat way i.e loop through array rather that boldly specify conditions in if statement ?

I am open for any suggestions and thanks in advance

Comment: What are you iterating over?  From what you describe you don't need a loop - perhaps try a SELECT CASE statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-select-case-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only a few values, an If Else is the easy answer. But here is how you would make an array:

```
Dim arrID() As Variant 'Array of Identifier values
Dim arrCol() As Variant 'Array of columns to stay unhidden

arrID = Array("111111111", "222222222", "333333333", "444444444", "555555555")
arrCol = Array("B:E", "F:I", "J:M", "N:Q", "R:U")

For i = LBound(arrID) To UBound(arrID)
    If Sheet1.[identifier].Text = arrID(i) Then
        Sheet2.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'Hide Everything
        Sheet2.Range("A:A," & arrCol(i)).Columns.Hidden = False 'Unhide column A and others
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

You will want to make sure arrID and arrCol have the same number of elements.

Comment: There are quite  few values so this should work like a charm. Thanks for your suggestions